# How to hide object between another object with transparent background color

Tags: coreldraw

I have two objects in Corel Draw: rectangle without background color and text (like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQWLf.png)). How can I make invisible the text´s part which is after the rectangle [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC0CD.png)? (Without setting the rectangles background color, I need it transparent)

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: You might want to move this to Graphic Design stack -- they answer a lot of these type of questions there.

Comment: OK, I will do it. Thank you. And may I have to delete this question?

Comment: I'd let a more senior user decide, they usually close a post if it's not right for this community.